# nodetool status in cassandra giving previous IP of nodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, nosql, cassandra

I am trying to expand a 2 node Cassandra Cluster to a 4 node cluster with 4 Amazon EC2 instances. I have created the four nodes  and made the following changes in cassandra.yaml file.

```
listen_address = 10.30.143.145 
seeds = 10.30.143.145,10.159.58.234,10.170.31.252,10.158.52.84
endpoint_snitch: Ec2snitch
num_tokens: 256
```

I have replicated these changes across all 4 nodes. I had expanded from single node cluster to double node cluster by following this procedure. However, after configuring the 4 node cluster, when I do a ./nodetool status on first node, I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-170-31-252:~/VIQ-Cloud/software/apache-cassandra-1.2.5/bin$ ./nodetool status
Datacenter: us-east
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.30.143.145  927.14 KB  256     16.1%  34d0424a-fe07-4047-a2a5-f45b9a0049d6  1a
UN  10.159.58.234  135.2 KB   256     15.7%  00308009-8755-4bce-906f-4eda53a31fc6  1a
UN  10.170.31.252  20.94 GB   256     20.9%  a815f0de-64db-418c-97a3-9aa7be280280  1a
UN  10.158.52.84   311.33 KB  256     15.0%  fc634f65-3cf3-4e24-a9a3-456adbd174e0  1a
Datacenter: UNKNOWN-DC
======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
DN  10.170.22.214  ?          256     16.6%  253ee376-c49d-47a1-a321-4f155870c122  UNKNOWN-RACK
DN  10.31.131.35   ?          256     15.7%  e94c0cb1-9635-42c9-8982-450271f7da1c  UNKNOWN-RACK
```

The address of the two nodes shown as DN is that of the previous private IP's of the other EC2 nodes (each reboot of EC2 instance changes the private IPs).
But the other 3 nodes is giving me proper result for nodetool status. I am wondering where cassandra is picking the previous IP's from because , they I havent mentioned them in the cassandra.yaml file.

I followed the [instructions here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/operations/add_replace_nodes) for adding new nodes.
Please advise on why this is happening.

Comment: Not sure about the old IP issue.  But when you add nodes to your cluster, do not make them seed nodes before you have bootstrapped them.  That is why no data got sent to them when they started. (one node 20GB other nodes 100kb)  If a node is a seed node, it will not go through the Cassandra bootstrap phase on first start, so it will not get its data.

Comment: @Zanson Thanks for that new insight.I was alway wondering s why data was concentrated on a node. That makes it clear. But I thought auto_booststrap is enabled in cassandra 1.2 by default.. Is that not the case..

Comment: It is. But there are a bunch of things that will cause it to turn off. Because you don't want nodes to bootstrap every time you reboot them. So being a seed node, already having data, already owning tokens, any of those things will disable auto bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this out, I think the answer may be that you need to make sure you are using the Ec2 or Ec2Multiregion snitch in your cassandra.yaml on the new nodes.  The fact that they got put in "UNKNOWN-DC" means the existing nodes don't know what DC to put them in.